# Is it possible to update the running process instance using Fluent API in camunda?

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler, bpmn.io

I am trying to make some changes in the runtime of a process using the Fluent API. Is it possible to update the running instance?

Ex:
If I want to add a new event between existing events (user Task, Service Task, ...) and run the newly added event. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as follows:

1. Create the new version of the process and deploy it.
2. Migrate the process instance to that version.

Minimal code example for step 2:

```
RuntimeService runtimeService = ..;
ProcessInstance processInstance = ..;

ProcessDefinition oldDefinition = ..;
ProcessDefinition newDefinition = ..;

MigrationPlan migrationPlan = runtimeService
  .createMigrationPlan(oldDefinition.getId(), newDefinition.getId())
  .mapEqualActivities()
  .build();

runtimeSerivce.newMigration(migrationPlan)
  .processInstanceIds(processInstance.getId())
  .execute();
```

Further reading:

- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/user-guide/process-engine/process-instance-migration/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to camunda and how can I make the ProcessDefinition from a BpmnModelInstance?

Comment: You deploy the model instance via the deployment API and then access the process definition via `RepositoryService#createProcessDefinitionQuery`. `ProcessDefinition` is the deployed thing.